# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_8: expected shape=(None, 898, 699, 1), found shape=(None, 699, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, reshape

I would like to reshape an array of dimensions 898 x 699 into expected `shape=(None, 898, 699, 1)` that is required by the convolutional neural network (CNN). I have tried using the command `np.expand_dims(model, axis=-1)` but when I pass its result into the CNN, it brings back this error message.

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_8: expected shape=(None, 898, 699, 1), found shape=(None, 699, 1)

How can I correct this?

This is my model summary

```
Model: "model_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_12 (InputLayer)        [(None, 898, 699, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_29 (Conv2D)           (None, 898, 699, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling (None, 449, 350, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_30 (Conv2D)           (None, 449, 350, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling (None, 225, 175, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_18 (Conv2DT (None, 450, 350, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_19 (Conv2DT (None, 900, 700, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_31 (Conv2D)           (None, 900, 700, 1)       289       
=================================================================
Total params: 28,353
Trainable params: 28,353
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input layer doesn't have compatible shape with the data you are feeding to the model. The data samples have size (None, 699, 1) (where None is the batch dimension). Maybe you don't mean your first dimension to be the batch dimension (I see that you want a dimension of size 899 too). Therefore, if you are using TF datasets, you could do something like:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
```

That would add a new dimension to the dataset and you will have a dataset shape of (None, 899, 699,1), which is compatible with your input shape.

Comment: I am using a numpy array not a TF dataset. How can I achieve this shape (None, 899, 699, 1) with numpy?

Comment: Then you could do something like: x= x[np.newaxis, :]  and y = y[np.newaxis, :]. Where x and y are your numpy arrays for input and output respectively